# resize partition, how?

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, vmware-workstation

i'm using ubuntu 14.04.
i have it on vmware.
at first i created the ubuntu machine on my drive C with 18GB space for the ubuntu machine. then i added another hard drive to my PC of 2TB (with Windows 7) and i set the drive of the machine in vmware to be 500GB.
i moved the vmware image from drive C to drive E (the big one).
but in the ubuntu i see 4 sda device. the first one is of 18 GB, the other two are extended and swap (i don't know what they r) and the last partition is the new big 500GB partition.

so now i have the boot partition (18GB) on sda1 and the new partition of 500GB on sda3.

how can i make the boot partition to be on the 500GB partition? i want to enlarge the 18GB to be 500GB and i don't need different partitions...

i also don't want to delete all my Ubuntu...

can someone help here?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

it's very simple dude 
use the utility already shipped with ubuntu called " Disks" 
Disks can dinamically change partitions size , but if the volume 
you gotta shrink or expand is the one u are using ( is mounted ) 
you better use a Live distro in order to do so....sysresccd ( http://www.sysresccd.org/)

Comment: sorry, but it doesn't work for me...

Comment: unfortunatly,
as i said the main partition (where Ubuntu is installed) that was privously on drive C is 18GB at most.
although i define the size of the hard disk in the vmware setting to be 500 GB total, i see in the disk utility that i have the main partition of 18GB and unmount partition of about 500 GB. even if i mount it it is another drive and does not extend the main drive.. :-(
is there a way to solve this? (sorry but i'm a newbee to all of this so specific instruction is needed)